# How to add a header image to my Wordpress plugin using git-svn?

Tags: wordpress, git-svn

I'm trying to use the [header image customization trick](http://make.wordpress.org/core/2011/12/21/been-giving-a-lot-of-thought-to-how/) that allows a wordpress plugin developer to display a customized header image on his Wordpress directory plugin page.

For that, I need to create a "assets" directory in my plugin root directory under svn (at the same level than trunk and branches), and put my image there. You can see the structure in place for [SEO by Yoast plugin](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/wordpress-seo/). The problem is that I want to achieve this using git-svn, not svn.

I have setup a git/svn repo and successfully pushed on svn trunk and even created a tag. I can see that the [assets](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/grayscale/) directory has been created for me on the svn repo, but I cannot figure out how to add a file on the directory.

The issue is that the "assets" directory is outside the svn standard layout and cannot be reached by branching. I think I will have to specify a non-standard layout somehow ?

Comment: Is your problem only with git-svn , not in achiving the task ?

Comment: @aravind.udayashankara Yes, I have already done it with svn. But this requires to manage a separate SVN repository. I would like to have only one git repository, and handle SVN updates via git-svn, like I do to manage trunk, branches and tags

Comment: @FabienQuatravaux yeah I would love to find a way to do this. If you have found a way could you please post it. Cheers mate.

Comment: Sorry @Paul, I still did not find a way do achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but hope this helps someone.

You can do this, but you'll need to manage the assets folder on a separate branch.

This will allow you to push changes to `http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/{plugin}/assets`  directly by setting up a seperate remote.

Assuming you already have your plugin setup locally under `git svn` create a new config for the assets url;

```
$ git config --add svn-remote.assets.url http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/{plugin}/assets
$ git config --add svn-remote.assets.fetch :refs/remotes/assets
$ git svn fetch -r HEAD assets
$ git checkout remotes/assets
$ git checkout -b assets
```

You're now on a new branch called `assets` that contains only the assets folder contents. Make your edits, commit, then use `git svn dcommit` to push your assets folder up.

Then simply switch back to your `master` branch, you're all done.